# How can I fill up select option menu from database with more fields?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a select option menu.
I fill it from the database:

```
$value = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM movies ORDER BY id DESC");
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($value))
{
    $release[$i] = $row->title;
    $i++;
}
```

And I write them out:

```
<select name="release"><?php 
foreach($release as $i){
    echo"<option value = '$i' > $i </option>";
}
?></select>
```

It works fine, but I would like to write the release year next to the title in the menu.
The release years are in the same movies table, in the release field.
How can I append the two fields' values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
$value = mysql_query("SELECT title, release FROM movies ORDER BY id DESC");
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($value))
{
    $release[$i] = $row->title . ' (' . $row->release . ')';
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Select both columns from the database and put the whole row object in your array:

```
$value = mysql_query("SELECT title, release_year FROM movies ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($value))
{
    $release[] = $row;
}
```

Then write them both out:

```
<select name="release"><?php 
foreach($release as $i => $r){
    echo"<option value = '$r->title' > $r->title ($r->release_year) </option>";
}
?></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: ***TESTED***

```
    <select name="release">
        <?php
        $value = "SELECT title, release_year FROM movies ORDER BY id DESC";
        $select=mysql_query($value);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
    {
        $title=$row['title'];
      $release_year=$row['release_year'];

     echo $title_rel_yr=$title.'('.$release_year.')';
            echo"<option value = '$title' >$title_rel_yr</option>";
                }       
        ?>
      </select>
```